# Shall I return if the global id is above the number of elements in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl

You can often see OpenCL kernels such as

```
kernel void aKernel(global float* input, global float* output, const uint N)
{
      const uint global_id = get_global_id(0);
      if (global_id >= N) return;
    // ...
}
```

I am wondering if this `if (global_id >= N) return;` is really necessary, especially if you create your buffer with the global size.

- In which cases they are mandatory?
- Is it a OpenCL code convention?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very common to have this conditional in OpenCL 1.x kernels because of the requirement that your global work size be an integer multiple of your work group size. So if you want to specify a work group size of 64 but have 1000 items to process you make the global size 1024, pass 1000 as a parameter (N), and do the check.

In OpenCL 2.0 the integer multiple restriction has been lifted so OpenCL 2.0 kernels are less likely to need this conditional.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a convention - it's the same as in regular C/C++, if you want to skip the rest of the function. It has the potential of speeding up execution, by not doing unnecessary work.

It may be necessary, if you have not padded your buffers to the size of the workgroup and you need to make sure that you are not accessing unallocated memory.

You have to be careful returning like this, because if there is a barrier in the kernel after the return you may deadlock the execution. This is because a barrier has to be reached by all work items in a work group. So if there's a barrier, either the condition needs to be true for whole work group, or it needs to be false for the whole work group.